# --show-mine option not showing any entries (az ad sp list --show-mine)

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

Consider the following:

```
// create a new service principal
PS C:\Users\myUser> az ad sp create-for-rbac
The output includes credentials that you must protect. Be sure that you do not include these credentials in your code or check the credentials into your source control. For more information, see https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli
{
  "appId": "...",
  "displayName": "...",
  "password": "...",
  "tenant": ".."
}

// list service principals created by me
PS C:\Users\myUser> az ad sp list --show-mine
[]
```

Why doesn't the second command `az ad sp list --show-mine` show the previously created service principal?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I have followed below process:

Firstly, I have logged in to Azure by using `az login`:

[image]

Then run the below command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac
```

[image]

Then run the below command:

```
 $x=az ad sp list --show-mine
 $x.displayName
 $s=$x | ConvertFrom-json
```

[image]

Then run the below command :

```
$s.displayName
```

[image]

You will get displayed the created Service Principal as mine got displayed.

Comment: very interesting. which version are you using?

Comment: azure cli version is 2.38.0.   For clear reference https://i.imgur.com/TApCgmK.png